# Homepage not working on production

Tags: error, production-mode

Everything works fine in development mode. But when I switch to production everything except homepage works. The only thing shown is this:

```
An error has happened during the application run. See exception log for details.
```

There is nothing written in `var/log/exception.log` at the time of homepage loading. So I am clueless as to why is this happening.

Comment: can you run composer update command after run magento rooting commands

Comment: Yes, all commands are running smoothly.

Comment: Can you please check your log files has proper write permission or not?

Comment: Check this link also: https://www.mageplaza.com/error-happened-during-application-run-see-expection-log-details.html

Answer (score 0):

Run magento 2 cli commands like
bin/magento set:up
bin/magento s:d:c
bin/magento s:s:d
bin/magento c:f
bin/magento c:c

clean your server cache

Comment: Already did the usual deploy comands. What do you mean by server cache?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting php.
E.g if php version is 7.4 try

sudo service php7.4-fpm restart

You usually need to be logged in as a root user to do this.

This will reset the opcache which I think will be your issue.

Note: to find your php version do php -v